# How to access pointer to 2-d array in c struct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am having trouble with following `struct` for using it as Matrix

```
  struct{
         int col;
         int row;
         int (*p)[col];//In this line compiler is giving error, saying col undeclared here.
  }Matrix;
```

I searched on internet and I found a solution which says to write

```
  int (*p)[col]
```

as

```
 int (*p)[]
```

Compiler passes it, no issues.

But when I want to increment p using `Matrix` variable say m

```
++(m.p);
```

compiler gives another errors (two) in the same line of code, which says

*increment of pointer to unknown structure.*
*arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type.*

Please tell me why the compiler is giving the above mentioned errors?

What I finally want is to have a pointer in the structure which points to 2-d *dynamic* array of integers.
So,How to do it???

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want a pointer to an arbitrary 2d array that changes, you will have to use a void pointer. (I don't recommend it, it's unsafe, design should probably be changed.)

```
struct
{
     int col;
     int row;
     void* p;
}
```

Before you access the memory, use a local variable-length array pointer. Take the void pointer in the struct, and assign to it the 
local vla pointer, using the information from the struct:

```
struct Matrix x = ...;

int (*n)[x.col] = x.p;
```

And then use it:

```
n[0][0] = ...
```

If you want to increment the void pointer in the struct, simply increment the local pointer, and assign it back to the void pointer:

```
n++;
x.p = n;
```

No casting is necessary, just a declaration of a local pointer. If that is a nuisance, operations on void pointer in the struct can be abstracted using inline functions. This should also be done for the sake of safety.

Comment: then what would  be the point of using struct as an abstraction??

Comment: @Rouftantical The struct holds the raw pointer to memory and its dimensions. Defining a local pointer is hardly a nuisance, and if it is for some reason, use get-set functions.

Comment: still it would be a headache of casting

Comment: @Rouftantical Actually, since it is a void pointer, no casting is necessary. See the example.

Answer (score 1):

The field declaration `int (*p)[col];` is not valid because the compiler don't know the value of *col*. What you need is a pointer to a pointer, `int **p`, where *p*[*i*] designates the *i*:th row in the two-dimensional array.

Here is a complete example with a convenient memory allocation macro:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) (ptr) = calloc((n) * sizeof (ptr)[0], sizeof (ptr)[0])

struct Matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **items;
};

void InitializeMatrix(int rows, int cols, struct Matrix *A)
{
    int i;

    A->rows = rows;
    A->cols = cols;
    NEW_ARRAY(A->items, rows);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        NEW_ARRAY(A->items[i], cols);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Matrix A;

    InitializeMatrix(10, 20, &A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you did sizeof(ptr)[0], can I write sizeof (ptr) alone?

Comment: @Rouftantical It's the array element size. In this context the element is either a matrix row or a matrix element. If you used `sizeof (ptr)` you would get the size of the pointer, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Rouftantical I also changed *malloc* to *calloc* to make all elements zero.

Answer (score 0):

When an array is declared then the memory needs to be allocated separately.

```
struct Matrix{
         int col;
         int row;
         int  *Matrix[100];
      };
```

More flexibile:

```
struct Matrix{
         int col;
         int row;
         int  **Matrix;
      }


struct Matrix A;

A.col =10;
A.row = 10;
```

/* Allocate memory here for the Matrix */

You can declare and allocate memory for a 2D arrays using different methods.

/* Access the Matrix */
    A.Matrix[i][j] = value;